# How to achieve triggered redirect after log in so that administration interface will be available on the redirected url?

Tags: redirection, rules, uri

I would like to ask for an advice. Recently, I was developing a conference site with Drupal 7. The site is hosted at domain1.com. However, the conference is covered by another organization and they require that conference page will be accessible from their own domain something like.: organization.com/conference2014 Fortunately, Drupal has base_url parameter and the site is accessible from organization.com/conference2014 domain. BUt, my problem is when I want to access administration interface of Drupal through organization.com/conference2014?q=user/login I get redirected to organization.com site which is administrated by the organization admin. Moreover, when I access again organization.com/conference2014 - it still asks me for the password.

I got adviced to introduce trigger after the user successfully logs in to the site organization.com/conference2014. It does redirect me but the administration interface/overlays is not there. Any ideas how to tackle this problem?

Martin

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You already asked this question, and you got an answer. If you don't understand how the answer applies to your case, ask the user who answered to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Login Destination](https://drupal.org/project/login_destination) , it will redirect you to the destination

> module allows you to customize the destination that a user is
>   redirected to after logging in, registering to the site (7.x), using a
>   one-time login link or logging out (7.x).
>
> The destination can be an internal page or an external URL.
>
> It is possible to specify certain
>   conditions like referring pages or user roles and make the destination
>   depend upon them. You may use PHP snippets to provide custom
>   conditions and destinations.
>
> It is also possible to keep users on the
>   currently visited page after logging in or out.

also take a look at [Login Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/login_redirect) module